# Search String in any table in Postgress?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgresql, I have 3 different tables `A`, `B` and `C`. `A` has a `Problem` column,  `B` has a `MedicalSolution` column and `C` has a `Diagnosis` column.

I have a string and I want to check in these 3 tables if they contain that string. How can I do this?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Please add sample data.

Comment: Please provide schema, sample data and expected output. Not voted down me.

Comment: Consider 3 columns from different 3 tables of type Varchar(50). I want to search name(eg.Belly) from a table which contains that name Belly. But the name of the columns is different table1 column Name1 , table2 column Name2 ,Table3 column Name3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get correctly, You need something like this:

```
select exists( select 1 from Table1 where Name1 like '%Belly%' )
union all 
select exists( select 1 from Table2 where Name2 like '%Belly%' )
union all 
select exists( select 1 from Table3 where Name3 like '%Belly%' )
```

If you need data, then

```
select 'Table1' as table_name  /*needed columns here*/ from Table1 where Name1 like '%Belly%' 
union all 
select 'Table2' as table_name  /*needed columns here*/ from Table2 where Name2 like '%Belly%'
```

remember that columns count and data types should match when use `union all`

Comment: It helps me solve issue, but it returns a boolean value and I want to select a date from particular table

Comment: @MaheshMaske - Check edited answer